# How to use an environment variable as prefix path while configuring NGINX?

Tags: linux, nginx, build, autotools, configure

I am trying to use `$NGINX_PREFIX` as a prefix to logging. At runtime the link editor should expand `$NGINX_PREFIX`. I am using the following command to build nginx:

```
./configure --prefix=\$NGINX_PREFIX --sbin-path=objs/nginx --conf-path=conf/nginx.conf --error-log-path=logs/error.log --http-log-path=logs/access.log
```

I am using environment variables is because I want to re-use the built binary on different machines.

But when I use the build binary file `objs/nginx`, it says the following:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "$NGINX_PREFIX/logs/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2018/08/22 17:54:08 [emerg] 16060#0: open() "$NGINX_PREFIX/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Now mind you I have correctly set the environment variables and the files for which errors are being shown above are already present.

Where am I going wrong? Is it because of the ENV variables? If yes, how can I get a pre-built nginx binary which I can re-use on multiple machines without building it again and again?

Comment: Why are you escaping the `$`?   If you want to use a variable, you should be letting the shell interpolate it.  Change your invocation to `configure --prefix=$NGINX_PREFIX ... `

Comment: Ah, I see what you are trying to do, but you are doing it in the wrong place.  You don't want to change the prefix to `configure`.  If you want a pre-built binary that can be installed in different locations, you need to move your changes several layers up the stack into the package management system.  Build a relocatable rpm and use alternate destination directories during installation.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Unfortunately I can't use any package manager in this case. Why doesn't NGINX directly provide a pre-built tarball which can be re-used? Seems a little weird to me. Is there any importance to building it on the same machine on which one is going to use it?

Comment: nginx provides rpms.  You could always extract the files from there and install them raw.

Comment: Bear in mind that a "pre-built tarball" *is* a package management system.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Sure, I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Extracting out the RPM and using the binary inside does not really work as it depends on other modules as well. Building one's own nginx and then using it's binary works, but runs into the problems of PATHS mentioned in the question.

Comment: You probably need to patch the Nginx sources to get the path from the environment (or patch the configuration file to be environment aware).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built nginx using the following commands:

```
./configure --error-log-path=stderr --http-log-path=stderr
make
```

And then I set all the necessary paths in my config file as **absolute paths**. Below is the config file contents:

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log /path/error.log;
pid /path/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    client_body_temp_path /path/client_body_temp;
    proxy_temp_path /path/proxy_temp;
    fastcgi_temp_path /path/fastcgi_temp;
    uwsgi_temp_path /path/uwsgi_temp;
    scgi_temp_path  /path/scgi_temp;

    sendfile  on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    upstream backend {
        server  127.0.0.1;
    }

    server {
        listen  3000;
        access_log  /path/access.log;
        location / {
            proxy_pass  http://backend;       
        }
    }
}
```

Use `objs/nginx -t -c /path/nginx.conf` to test your config file.
And `objs/nginx -c /path/nginx.conf` to start the nginx server.

**NOTE: All the paths in the config file as well as the paths that you pass in the CLI arguments must be absolute paths. Providing relative paths, at least in the version 1.14.0 fails, and it falls back to the default ones you provided while building NGINX**

Comment: To set the prefix at run time, just call nginx like this `nginx -p \`pwd\`/ -c nginx.conf`. Now the prefix parameter must still be absolute, but you don't have to manually set all paths that depend on prefix in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to use `$NGINX_PREFIX` as a prefix to logging. At runtime
>   the link editor should expand `$NGINX_PREFIX`.

That doesn't make any sense at all.  The link editor (a.k.a. "linker") has its full effect at compile time.  It is not involved at run time.  Depending on the form of the executable, there may be a dynamic linker involved at runtime, but that's a somewhat different beast.  In any event, neither variety of linker has anything to do with manipulating *data* in the executable or its address space.  Linkers are about matching symbols with *addresses*.

> I am using the following command to build nginx:
>
> ```
> ./configure --prefix=\$NGINX_PREFIX --sbin-path=objs/nginx --conf-path=conf/nginx.conf --error-log-path=logs/error.log --http-log-path=logs/access.log
> ```

That seems particularly unlikely do do anything useful, because the primary purpose of the `--prefix` option of an Autotools configure script is to set a prefix for *installation directories*.  The default is `/usr/local`, and `/usr` is a common alternative.  If you set the prefix to something that is not a valid installation path prefix then at minimum you render the package's installation targets non-functional.

> how can I get a pre-built nginx binary which I can re-use on multiple machines without building it again and again?

This is exactly what packages and package management are about.  Build an RPM, or a DEB, or whatever your target systems require, and use it to install the software.  You may even find such packages pre-built for your target system type, and / or you may find packaging sources appropriate for you to use in building your own custom packages.  Or invent your own packaging format, which may be as simple as a tarball with an accompanying installation script.

But all of that packaging business seems orthogonal to the logging prefix question you started with.  If the destination log directory is compiled into the software and there is not already a mechanism for overriding that at runtime (config file, command-line option, already-recognized environment variable, ...), then you cannot magic such a thing in.  You will need to modify the program to introduce such a capability.

But do consider simply not doing so.  Specify a custom log directory during the build if you wish -- that's perfectly fine -- but not everything has to be configurable at runtime.